# Toggle between images in a textbox in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have an SSRS report and have a column which has to display images. I have two images in my report. I want to toggle between the two based on that condition. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can switch between them based on a conditional:

You can do:

`=IIf(Fields!FieldName.Value = "ValueForImage1", "Image1.jpg", "Image2.jpg")`

or preform an actual Switch Statement:

`Switch(
Fields!FieldName.Value = "ValueForImage1", "Image1.jpg", 
Fields!FieldName.Value = "ValueForImage2", "Image2.jpg")`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Tried that but it only prints Image1.jpg or Image2.jpg. I also made sure to add the images to the project but somehow they are not recognized. Wondering if I need to mention the path.

Comment: What is the condition you are trying to use them against? Where is that placed(in a text box; in row with a grouping, multiple groupings? etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming by column you mean you are using the `Tablix` in your report, FOr showing up the image in the tablix cell you need to add the `Image` control in that cell,

GOTO -> **RightClick Cell WIth Image Control -> Image Properties -> Genral -> Select the Image Source -> Embedded**

Then right below it there is box for the image source in right side of that textbox you can click on expression button.

Then set the expression as

```
   =IIF(Fields!FieldName.Value = "ValueForImage1", "Image1", "Image2")
```

Remove the image name extension from the image name value.